# Microsoft Dynamics GP Session Central Service does not start

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, service, windows-service, microsoft-dynamics-gp

ITNOA

All GP services started except GP session central service. When I want to start it, I see the below error in Event Viewer.

```
GP session central: An argument pointing to a valid servicehost config file is missing.
```

This is a very bad problem because I cannot use the web client while this problem exists. How to fix this problem?

My platform is

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express SP1
Microsoft Dynamics GP 2015 R2
```

If any other information may be useful for troubleshooting please tell me.

Comment: See if this helps any . . . https://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/151405

Comment: @PJMahoney thx for response but this cannot any help me.

Comment: Please do not cross post across sites. Most communities frown on this. You can delete questions you have created that do not have any answers.

Comment: @Paul As you say I delete super user question. thx for notice me. I hope to find my answer here.

Comment: Very good. Please edit the question to remove the link.

Comment: @Paul I removed the link in my question. :)